# Is it possible to authencticating/login for WPA2-Enterprise using web portal?

Tags: security, authentication, wifi

I just wondering is it possible using WPA2-Enterprise with authentication using web just like captive portal? If possible I think it would be really cool though the setup will take time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

WPA2 Enterprise requires successful authentication **before** any data can be transmitted to/from the client. This obviously precludes serving a web form to the user before they're authenticated to the network.

Comment: thank you very much for your explanation EEAA, now it really clear to me how WPA2 Enterprise work :).